# Wordpress v2.9.2 fails to create databases on MAMP

Tags: mysql, wordpress, installation

I am familiar with previous Wordpress installers, but in this new version I've hit something new that I don't see documented.

I am attempting to install wordpress to MAMP as my localhost and I'm getting errors that indicate the table creation has failed.

PHP: 5.2.11

MySQL: 5.1.37

I've used the installer interface to set db settings and I've also tried it manually, with no difference.

I get the following errors on the installation success screen. The tables wp-commentmeta and wp-links are created and I am given a login/password - even though tables for users are not be created.

```
WordPress database error: [MyISAM table 'wp_terms' is in use (most likely by a MERGE table). Try FLUSH TABLES.]
CREATE TABLE wp_terms ( term_id bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment, name varchar(200) NOT NULL default '', slug varchar(200) NOT NULL default '', term_group bigint(10) NOT NULL default 0, PRIMARY KEY (term_id), UNIQUE KEY slug (slug), KEY name (name) ) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8

WordPress database error: [MyISAM table 'wp_term_taxonomy' is in use (most likely by a MERGE table). Try FLUSH TABLES.]
CREATE TABLE wp_term_taxonomy ( term_taxonomy_id bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment, term_id bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL default 0, taxonomy varchar(32) NOT NULL default '', description longtext NOT NULL, parent bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL default 0, count bigint(20) NOT NULL default 0, PRIMARY KEY (term_taxonomy_id), UNIQUE KEY term_id_taxonomy (term_id,taxonomy), KEY taxonomy (taxonomy) ) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8

WordPress database error: [MyISAM table 'wp_term_relationships' is in use (most likely by a MERGE table). Try FLUSH TABLES.]
CREATE TABLE wp_term_relationships ( object_id bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL default 0, term_taxonomy_id bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL default 0, term_order int(11) NOT NULL default 0, PRIMARY KEY (object_id,term_taxonomy_id), KEY term_taxonomy_id (term_taxonomy_id) ) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8

WordPress database error: [MyISAM table 'wp_comments' is in use (most likely by a MERGE table). Try FLUSH TABLES.]
CREATE TABLE wp_comments ( comment_ID bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment, comment_post_ID bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL default '0', comment_author tinytext NOT NULL, comment_author_email varchar(100) NOT NULL default '', comment_author_url varchar(200) NOT NULL default '', comment_author_IP varchar(100) NOT NULL default '', comment_date datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00', comment_date_gmt datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00', comment_content text NOT NULL, comment_karma int(11) NOT NULL default '0', comment_approved varchar(20) NOT NULL default '1', comment_agent varchar(255) NOT NULL default '', comment_type varchar(20) NOT NULL default '', comment_parent bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL default '0', user_id bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL default '0', PRIMARY KEY (comment_ID), KEY comment_approved (comment_approved), KEY comment_post_ID (comment_post_ID), KEY comment_approved_date_gmt (comment_approved,comment_date_gmt), KEY comment_date_gmt (comment_date_gmt) ) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8

WordPress database error: [MyISAM table 'wp_options' is in use (most likely by a MERGE table). Try FLUSH TABLES.]
CREATE TABLE wp_options ( option_id bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment, blog_id int(11) NOT NULL default '0', option_name varchar(64) NOT NULL default '', option_value longtext NOT NULL, autoload varchar(20) NOT NULL default 'yes', PRIMARY KEY (option_id), UNIQUE KEY option_name (option_name) ) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8

WordPress database error: [MyISAM table 'wp_postmeta' is in use (most likely by a MERGE table). Try FLUSH TABLES.]
CREATE TABLE wp_postmeta ( meta_id bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment, post_id bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL default '0', meta_key varchar(255) default NULL, meta_value longtext, PRIMARY KEY (meta_id), KEY post_id (post_id), KEY meta_key (meta_key) ) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8

WordPress database error: [MyISAM table 'wp_posts' is in use (most likely by a MERGE table). Try FLUSH TABLES.]
CREATE TABLE wp_posts ( ID bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment, post_author bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL default '0', post_date datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00', post_date_gmt datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00', post_content longtext NOT NULL, post_title text NOT NULL, post_excerpt text NOT NULL, post_status varchar(20) NOT NULL default 'publish', comment_status varchar(20) NOT NULL default 'open', ping_status varchar(20) NOT NULL default 'open', post_password varchar(20) NOT NULL default '', post_name varchar(200) NOT NULL default '', to_ping text NOT NULL, pinged text NOT NULL, post_modified datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00', post_modified_gmt datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00', post_content_filtered text NOT NULL, post_parent bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL default '0', guid varchar(255) NOT NULL default '', menu_order int(11) NOT NULL default '0', post_type varchar(20) NOT NULL default 'post', post_mime_type varchar(100) NOT NULL default '', comment_count bigint(20) NOT NULL default '0', PRIMARY KEY (ID), KEY post_name (post_name), KEY type_status_date (post_type,post_status,post_date,ID), KEY post_parent (post_parent) ) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8

WordPress database error: [MyISAM table 'wp_users' is in use (most likely by a MERGE table). Try FLUSH TABLES.]
CREATE TABLE wp_users ( ID bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment, user_login varchar(60) NOT NULL default '', user_pass varchar(64) NOT NULL default '', user_nicename varchar(50) NOT NULL default '', user_email varchar(100) NOT NULL default '', user_url varchar(100) NOT NULL default '', user_registered datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00', user_activation_key varchar(60) NOT NULL default '', user_status int(11) NOT NULL default '0', display_name varchar(250) NOT NULL default '', PRIMARY KEY (ID), KEY user_login_key (user_login), KEY user_nicename (user_nicename) ) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8

WordPress database error: [MyISAM table 'wp_usermeta' is in use (most likely by a MERGE table). Try FLUSH TABLES.]
CREATE TABLE wp_usermeta ( umeta_id bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment, user_id bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL default '0', meta_key varchar(255) default NULL, meta_value longtext, PRIMARY KEY (umeta_id), KEY user_id (user_id), KEY meta_key (meta_key) ) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8
```

And then **alot** of messages saying updates/inserts etc failed because the table doesn't exist.

Anyone encountered this before?

EDIT: MAMP reports port 8889 for mysql, so I changed the hostname in wp-config to localhost:8889. Which hasn't worked.

EDIT: I fixed this. I had a previous database for wordpress which I deleted and re-created repeatedly trying to solve this problem. 
Apparently deleting it wasn't good enough as the problem was solved by creating a database called newwordpress and using that instead.

MySQL must retain some data from deleted databases.

Comment: Are you 100% sure you are doing this on an empty database?

Comment: When I look in phpmyadmin it certainly looks empty. I've dropped all the tables in the database for each new attempt.

Comment: Did you check that the user you have has write / create table permissions ( not just read , selects ? )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you have the correct port for your MAMP database? I forgot to do so and it was hitting the default mySQL server on my machine.

EDIT: The port number for your MAMP installation is specified in the settings dialog. By default, it's probably 8889. You can read the [WordPress documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#MySQL_Alternate_Port) about how to specify a non-default mySQL port.

Comment: MAMP produces this in the url: localhost:8888
Which I thought was the default Wordpress port

Comment: That's the Apache port. The mySQL server is started on a different port. Look in the settings dialog for MAMP, or just assume that because you didn't change it, it's 8889.

Answer (score 0):

Use phpmyadmin to see if the database was even created. If not, create the database: [3. MySQL (MAMP & MAMP PRO Documentation)](http://documentation.mamp.info/en/mamp-pro/server/mysql)

Comment: I am using a pre-existing database. Wordpress is at least finding that as it is creating two tables on it before breaking.

Comment: Start a new database with phpmyadmin:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress_Locally_on_Your_Mac_With_MAMP